# What is the difference between browser. vs driver. commands webdriver.io

Tags: testing, automated-tests, webdriver, mocha.js

What is the difference between the two in webdriver.io? Do they have the same function? Are they completely different things?

I use driver.pause(3000) sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

The driver and browser objects for webdriver.io are the same. It is just semantically more correct to use "driver" instead of "browser" when working with mobile applications. So driver.pause and browser.pause are the same.

Note that it is not recommended to use pause when waiting for elements to show up. https://webdriver.io/docs/api/browser/pause